# Parsing bad ISO format into a good date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

How can one parse this line into a good date in javascript?

2013-12-19T06:59:27.888+3:00

I think the main problem is the milliseconds. I'm hoping to use moment.js to parse the date into a nicer format as well, I thought it could parse unix style timestamps, but couldn't get it to work with these types.

moment("2013-12-19T06:59:27.888+3:00").format("Do MM YYYY");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a (one of the many) *valid* [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

> Decimal fractions may be added to any of the three time elements. However, a fraction may only be added to the lowest order time element in the representation..

If momentjs doesn't accept it as ISO 8601 by default (the fractional seconds + offset format is *not* listed in ["supported across all browsers"](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/)<sup>1</sup>), the format is [easy to manually specify](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) :

```
var fmt = "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSSZZ";
var d = moment(str, fmt);
```

---

From the [momentjs source](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/moment.js), that ISO format *should* be accepted, assuming the comment doesn't lie and it [Works Here (TM)](http://jsfiddle.net/B88yr/1/) against MomentJS 2.2.1.

```
// iso 8601 regex
// 0000-00-00 0000-W00 or 0000-W00-0 + T + 00 or 00:00 or 00:00:00 or 00:00:00.000 + +00:00 or +0000 or +00)
isoRegex = /^\s*(?:[+-]\d{6}|\d{4})-(?:(\d\d-\d\d)|(W\d\d$)|(W\d\d-\d)|(\d\d\d))((T| )(\d\d(:\d\d(:\d\d(\.\d+)?)?)?)?([\+\-]\d\d(?::?\d\d)?|\s*Z)?)?$/,
```

Comment: Updated above with moment js

Comment: What about the `+3:00`?  Is that supposed to represent the time zone?

Comment: Yes, there are a variety of timezone stamps added onto the end as well.

Comment: @Organiccat Whoops, fixed the format. momentjs uses `SSS` (`fff` is from .NET).

Comment: Thanks, it appears to accept the formatting now! Didn't know you could define your own format fractionals :)

Comment: @Organiccat It might also be an .. older moment? http://jsfiddle.net/B88yr/1/ "works here"